# How do I position my pivot table filters above each other using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, filter, pivot-table

Basically, I have multiple tabs I am putting together, each with multiple pivots, where each pivot has multiple filters built in. These need to be visible to confirm the data you are seeing, since non-developers wouldn't know, how to access or understand VBA code.

What I want: Pivot table filters to be over each other in a list form:

[image: Desired Result]

What I currently get:

[image: VBA code Result]

Here is a simplified version of the code...please let me know if there is a better way of doing this!

I tried using the Record Macro button in excel and format everything as I wanted to see, but once I actually run the macro, the filters are side by side rather than on top of each other.

```
Sub Macro5()
    Columns("A:A").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False


    Dim dataname As String
    Dim datasheetname As String
    Dim pivotsheetname As String

    dataname = ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).Name
    datasheetname = ActiveSheet.Name
    pivotsheetname = datasheetname & " Pivot"


    Sheets.Add

    ActiveSheet.Name = pivotsheetname

    ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
        dataname, Version:=6).CreatePivotTable TableDestination:= _
        "'" & pivotsheetname & "'!R3C1", TableName:="PivotTable15", 
    DefaultVersion:=6
    Sheets(pivotsheetname).Select
    Cells(3, 1).Select
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable15")
        .ColumnGrand = False
        .HasAutoFormat = True
        .DisplayErrorString = False
        .DisplayNullString = True
        .EnableDrilldown = True
        .ErrorString = ""
        .MergeLabels = False
        .NullString = ""
        .PageFieldOrder = 2
        .PageFieldWrapCount = 0
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RowGrand = False
        .SaveData = True
        .PrintTitles = False
        .RepeatItemsOnEachPrintedPage = True
        .TotalsAnnotation = False
        .CompactRowIndent = 3
        .InGridDropZones = False
        .DisplayFieldCaptions = True
        .DisplayMemberPropertyTooltips = False
        .DisplayContextTooltips = True
        .ShowDrillIndicators = True
        .PrintDrillIndicators = False
        .AllowMultipleFilters = False
        .SortUsingCustomLists = True
        .FieldListSortAscending = False
        .ShowValuesRow = False
        .CalculatedMembersInFilters = False
        .RowAxisLayout xlTabularRow
    End With
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable15").PivotCache
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .MissingItemsLimit = xlMissingItemsDefault
    End With
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable15").RepeatAllLabels xlRepeatLabels
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable15").PivotFields("Billable?")
        .Orientation = xlPageField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable15").PivotFields("Billed")
        .Orientation = xlPageField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable15").PivotFields("Amount")
    enter code here       .Orientation = xlPageField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable15").AddDataField 
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
        "PivotTable15").PivotFields("Qty"), "Sum of Qty", xlSum
End Sub
```

Comment: I don't understand your current behavior vs your expected behavior - could you please try to upload the pictures once more? *"These need to be visible to confirm the data you are seeing since non-developers wouldn't know how to access or understand VBA code."* This makes no sense to me - why would your users being seeing any VBA code at all?

Comment: Hi Dwirony, I added the images of desired result vs what I get with my code. Sorry for the confusing wording. The images show the data filters, and those filters need to be visible so the end-user can maybe make adjustments or simply know how the overall data is filters. Basically, i am using the same data set to create 5 separate tabs in which each tab shows the same data set but filtered differently. So, when looking at each tab, the end-user can understand the difference by looking at the filters on top.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order of the filter fields is defined by the parameter `PageFieldOrder`, which can be:

- `xlOverThenDown` (= 2, your previous result)
- `xlDownThenOver` (= 1, your desired result)

I optimized your code additionally:

- normally, it i not necessary to [select or activate anything](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10714251/10908769)
- I added two variables to reference the pivotcache and the pivottable objects
- the datafield can be added similar to the other pivotfields, but their name has to be set afterwards

---

```
Sub GenerateNewPivottable()
    Dim datasheetname As String
    Dim dataname As String
    Dim pivotsheetname As String
    Dim pc As PivotCache
    Dim pt As PivotTable

    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    dataname = ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).Name
    datasheetname = ActiveSheet.Name
    pivotsheetname = datasheetname & " Pivot"

    Sheets.Add
    ActiveSheet.Name = pivotsheetname

    Set pc = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create( _
        SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
        SourceData:=dataname)
    With pc
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .MissingItemsLimit = xlMissingItemsDefault ' better: xlMissingItemsNone
    End With

    Set pt = pc.CreatePivotTable( _
        TableDestination:="'" & pivotsheetname & "'!R3C1", _
        TableName:="PivotTable15")

    With pt
        .ColumnGrand = False
        .HasAutoFormat = True
        .DisplayErrorString = False
        .DisplayNullString = True
        .EnableDrilldown = True
        .ErrorString = ""
        .MergeLabels = False
        .NullString = ""
        .PageFieldOrder = XlOrder.xlDownThenOver
        .PageFieldWrapCount = 0
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RowGrand = False
        .SaveData = True
        .PrintTitles = False
        .RepeatItemsOnEachPrintedPage = True
        .TotalsAnnotation = False
        .CompactRowIndent = 3
        .InGridDropZones = False
        .DisplayFieldCaptions = True
        .DisplayMemberPropertyTooltips = False
        .DisplayContextTooltips = True
        .ShowDrillIndicators = True
        .PrintDrillIndicators = False
        .AllowMultipleFilters = False
        .SortUsingCustomLists = True
        .FieldListSortAscending = False
        .ShowValuesRow = False
        .CalculatedMembersInFilters = False
        .RowAxisLayout xlTabularRow
        .RepeatAllLabels xlRepeatLabels
    End With


    With pt.PivotFields("Billable?")
        .Orientation = xlPageField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    With pt.PivotFields("Billed")
        .Orientation = xlPageField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    With pt.PivotFields("Amount")
        .Orientation = xlPageField
        .Position = 1
    End With

    With pt.PivotFields("Qty")
        .Orientation = xlDataField
        .Function = xlSum
        .Name = "Sum of Qty"
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Didn't think it was that easy but yes, that works. Thank you!!